# Use variabile $_global on remote server

Tags: php, include, remote-access

I want to include the variabile `$_GLOBAL` on many websites which are not hosted in the same place. 
Or include the file that contains some functions in different sites on different servers.

Everything is done remotely.

I do't want the file to kept on the servers where websites are kept, are 150 websites.

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: You might consider a cache server, such as memcache or redis, making it accessible to all your webservers

Comment: Just a note to what @Mark Baker said: if you do so - don't forget about making it protected somehow. IE: memcache doesn't support authentication (for obvious reasons)

Comment: Sounds like a job for a database server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to host a data, use `database`.

If you want to host some remote functions, create a server and create an API so that you can call all the functions remotely. Don't forget some authentication like a `secret` used in social apps.

Comment: I think it to use a remote database but i can't have access on websites $_POST,$_GET,$_SESSION,etc remote.With api i think i do a file that i put on evry root directory and include it that has in it all the function that api produced?

Comment: By API I meant create a server that can run all the functions. Then call this API remotely using cURL. Use `url` as the indicator for which function you want to run and `$_POST` to send arguments to functions. API can return a JSON encoded string for easy access.

Comment: It's ok but i don't have access to hole global variabiles on the remote server and call it evry time that _POST,_GET,etc is called.

Comment: @Cosmin I don't understand. Can you put it in a different words?

Comment: nevermind it's ok ideea, i will try to implemntate. Thank you.